# Unknown provider error when trying to inject a service from another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen several posts on unknown provider errors but none of them have addressed my particular problem. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userAccountResourceProvider <- userAccountResource <- AdminUserAccountsCtrl
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="rpms">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- Application Script -->
    <script src="App/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="Common/services/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="Common/services/userAccountResource.js"></script>
    <script src="Common/services/userAccountResourceMock.js"></script>

    <!-- Admin Controller Scripts -->
    <script src="App/admin/adminUserAccountsCtrl.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="doOnLoad()" class="administration-page user-account-page">

    <div id="main" ng-controller="AdminUserAccountsCtrl as vm">
        <div class="main-content with-sidebar">
            <h2>User Accounts</h2>
            <div id="managed-user-accounts" class="module">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Full Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="account in vm.userAccounts">
                            <td>{{ account.username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ account.firstName}} {{ account.lastName }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js;

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("rpms",
                             ["common.services"]);

}());
```

Here is my second module - common.services.js:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services",
                ["ngResource"]);
}());
```

And here is my userAccountResource service declaration in the common.services module:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("userAccountResource"
                 ["$resource",
                  userAccountResource]);

    function userAccountResource($resource) {
        return $resource("/api/accounts/:accountId");
    }

}());
```

Finally, here is my AdminUserAccountsCtrl controller declaration - using this is causing the error:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("rpms")
        .controller("AdminUserAccountsCtrl",
                    ["userAccountResource",
                     adminUserAccountsCtrl]);

    function adminUserAccountsCtrl(userAccountResource) {
        var vm = this;

        userAccountResource.query(function(data) {
            vm.userAccounts = data;
        });
    }

}());
```

I know that the userAccountResource is created under the common.services module but the common.services module is included as a dependency of the rpms module. Why is it considered an unknown provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `,` after `"userAccountResource"` like this

```
 .factory("userAccountResource",  //, here was missing
             ["$resource",
              userAccountResource]);
```

Comment: why did you format your entire answer as if it were a code block?  Looking through your post history, it seems you have done this with every one of your answers.  It does not make the answer more readable....

Comment: she might be new user, thats why

Comment: @Subhashini The menu bar above answerbox textarea could help you writing more formatted answers, try to play with them while answering.

Comment: Thanks, Claies; I just completely missed that comma. That fixed it.

Comment: Although I can't believe I did not get a more informative error message, javascript parse warning - something. I had "use strict";